# How to declare a variable and use it in an if statement in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm wanting to create a variable based on a query result and then use it in an IF statement. I have this so far:

```
with variable as (select "Id" from public.tableName where "OtherId" = 24)

if variable notnull then
    insert into public.tableName ("OtherName", "OtherPhoneNumber", "OtherAddress", "Id")
    overriding system values
    values ('foo', '205-123-4567', '123 Sample Ln', variable)
end if
```

Postgres gives me an error that reads:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "if"

What am I doing wrong?

****edit: Id is not the primary key, as there is a different primary key named TableNameId****

Comment: I don't get the first CTE.  If you expect `Id = 24`, then wouldn't you also know what the value of `Id` would be returned from the select?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I guess it's supposed to be an `IF EXISTS(…)`

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Is `"Id"` the primary or a unique key? If yes, you can simply use `insert ... on conflict do nothing` instead

Comment: if `Id` is not unique then the whole IF doesn't make sense as the "variable" would only be able to contain a **single** value, not multiple. And to which value should `variable` be set anyway? The `Name`?  If yes, then it seems rather strange that you want to store "a name" into an integer column.

Comment: I'm wanting to get a variables Id, then create another entry with the same Id. This Id would not be the primary key, so I would be able to create another variable with 2 of the same Id's.

Comment: And what if there is more than one row that matches `id = 24`? As far as I can tell, GMB's answer does exactly what you want

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a given id exists in one table and insert into *another table* if there is a match, you can use the `insert ... select` syntax as follows:

```
insert into public.tableName2 ("OtherName", "OtherPhoneNumber", "OtherAddress", "Id")
select 'foo', '205-123-4567', '123 Sample Ln', "Id"
from public.tableName1
where "Id" = 24
```

Comment: I'm wanting this to take place in one table. I want to check for if a certain value exists, then add another value. If not, then don't do anything.

Comment: @ColbyWilloughby It works with the same table instead of two separate tables just as well. However, then it looks like your `Id` column is not unique, which would be rather weird.